# Can "auprès de" have a different meaning, depending on its position in this sentence?

Tags: sens

> On avait déjà l’habitude de ne pas trop s’étendre sur son salaire ***auprès de ses amis***. Voilà que dire ce sur quoi on travaille peut être compromettant. Bientôt, on ne dévoilera même plus le nom de son employeur.

I wonder if "auprès de" is used here to qualify "son salaire" and compare their different pay grades? Or for this specific meaning, do you need to phrase it as:

> son salaire auprès de ***celui*** de ses amis?

In any case, if you have in mind the meaning of "go into detail about his salary ***around his friends***" in the sense of "in close physical proximity with his friends", is it better to move "auprès de" to right after "s’étendre"?

> vs: On avait déjà l’habitude de ne pas trop s’étendre ***auprès de ses amis*** sur son salaire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dans les deux cas :

> On avait déjà l’habitude de ne pas trop s’étendre sur son salaire auprès de ses amis.
>
> On avait déjà l’habitude de ne pas trop s’étendre auprès de ses amis sur son salaire.

il n'y a pour moi aucune ambiguïté, *auprès de* est employé pour exprimer la proximité spatiale, et on pourrait le remplacer par *devant* /*en présence de*.

Pour exprimer une comparaison dans les salaires je tournerais la phrase tout autrement :

> On avait déjà l’habitude de ne pas trop s’étendre sur son salaire comparé à celui de ses amis.

Voici une phrase où **auprès de** exprime une comparaison :

> Son salaire est élevé auprès de celui de ses amis. (Leurs salaires sont élevés auprès de ceux de ses/leurs amis).

On peut aussi avoir deux substantifs différents :

> Ce petit incident n'est rien auprès du grand vide qu'a laissé son départ.

Answer (score 3):

**No. The meaning does not change depending on its position in the sentence.**

Your translation is correct ("around his friends"), as a french synonym of "auprès de" would be "a proximité de".

The position of the group "auprès de ses amis" is variable, and both are perfectly correct and usable. Naturally, I would use the first one ("auprès" at the end).

Placing the group just after "s'étendre" might seem a *little* old-fashioned.